# Cannot access a disposed object Entity framework core and .net core web api Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'PTEAContext'

DBContext.cs below

```
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

}
```

}
}

EFRepo Class and error is in while adding User entity

namespace Infrastructure.Data
{

```
public class EfRepository<T> : IAsyncRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected readonly PTEAContext _dbContext;

    public EfRepository(PTEAContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public virtual async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAllAsync()
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAsync(ISpecification<T> spec)
    {
        return await ApplySpecification(spec).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<int> CountAsync(ISpecification<T> spec)
    {
        return await ApplySpecification(spec).CountAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return entity;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
        public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task DeleteAsync(T entity)
        {
            _dbContext.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private IQueryable<T> ApplySpecification(ISpecification<T> spec)
        {
            return SpecificationEvaluator<T>.GetQuery(_dbContext.Set<T>().AsQueryable(), spec);
        }
}
}
```

I have done lot of RND but not able to find the solution where is error.

Comment: you should edit your question to include the stacktrace and show relevant code related to where the error happens.

Comment: Its very hard to add code. But I tried to add much code as possible. Error is in when AddAsysnc method

Comment: I didn't mean for you to remove the startup code you had before, you should add that back so we can see the lifetime of the dependencies

Comment: Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
            services.AddAutoMapper();
            
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddDbContext<PTEAContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));
            services.AddScoped<IUsersService, UsersService>();

Comment: Do you await `AddAsync` method when you call it?